# How can I find a key in a map based on a pattern matching in java?

Tags: java, regex

I want to find keys in a map with a pattern matching.

```
Ex:-   
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("address1", "test test test");
    map.put("address2", "aaaaaaaaaaa");
    map.put("fullname", "bla bla");
```

From above map, I want to get the values of keys which has prefix of "address". So as in this example output should be the first two results ("address1" and "address2").

How can I achieve this dynamically?

Comment: There is no way by using only `get()` you will have to use something like `entrySet()` and loop over the keys to do a regex match

Comment: What version of Java are you using ?

Answer (score 29):

You can grab the `keySet` of the map and then filter to get only keys that starts with "address" and add the valid keys to a new Set.

With Java 8, it's a bit less verbose:

```
Set<String> set = map.keySet()
                     .stream()
                     .filter(s -> s.startsWith("address"))
                     .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 13):

If you have Java 8 features, something like this should work:

```
    Set<String> addresses = map.entrySet()
                               .stream()
                               .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().startsWith("address"))
                               .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                               .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: All good, but I think this will give the `values` not the `keys`

Comment: yeah, the original question asked for the values of keys which has prefix of "address"

Answer (score 11):

Something like this:

```
    for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey().startsWith("address")) {
            // do stuff with entry
        }
    }
```

Comment: That should be `entry.getKey()...` not `entry.getValue()...`.

Answer (score 4):

I created an interface...

```
import java.util.Map;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface MapLookup {
    <V> List<V> lookup(String regularExpression, Map<String,V> map);
}
```

And the implementation

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MapLookupImpl implements MapLookup {
    @Override
    public <V> List<V> lookup(String regularExpression, Map<String, V> map) {
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regularExpression);
        List<String> values  = map.keySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(string -> pattern.matcher(string).matches())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        if(values!= null && !values.isEmpty()){
            return values.stream().map((key) -> map.get(key)).collect(Collectors.toList());

        }
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

The test

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("foo",3);
    map.put("bar",42);
    map.put("foobar",-1);

    MapLookup lookup = new MapLookupImpl();

    List<Integer> values = lookup.lookup("\\woo\\w*",map);

    System.out.println(values);
}
```

The result

```
[-1, 3]
```

Or maybe that's overkill.  I can see a repeated use for this, though.

For those who want the pre-java8 version:

```
    public class PreJava8MapLookup implements MapLookup {
    @Override
    public <V> List<V> lookup(String regularExpression, Map<String, V> map) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regularExpression).matcher("");
        Iterator<String> iterator = map.keySet().iterator();
        List<V> values = new ArrayList<>();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            String key = iterator.next();
            if(matcher.reset(key).matches()){
                values.add(map.get(key));
            }
        }
        return values;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I came across a similar need and attempted implementing a POC for such a data structure. I came to the conclusion its much more practical to partition data in some manner :)

However, if you really have your mind set on implementing something like that you would need a structure more similar to a trie tree. Here is what I got (my apologies since the code is in Scala but it can easily be adapted and if you put your mind to it you can probably finish it and make it useable)

```
    package component.datastructure

import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

class RegExpLookup[T] {

  private val root = new mutable.HashMap[Char, Node]

  def put(key: String, value: T): Unit = {
    addNode(key.toCharArray, 0, root, value)
    println(root.toString)
  }

  private def addNode(key: Array[Char], charIdx: Int,
                      currentRoot: mutable.Map[Char, Node], value: T): Unit = {
    if (charIdx < key.length - 1) {
      if (currentRoot.contains(key(charIdx))) {
        addNode(key, charIdx + 1, currentRoot(key(charIdx)).nodeRoot, value)
      } else {
        val node = Node(null, new mutable.HashMap[Char, Node])
        currentRoot.put(key(charIdx), node)
        addNode(key, charIdx + 1, node.nodeRoot, value)
      }
    } else {
      currentRoot.put(key(charIdx), Node(value, null))
    }
  }

  private def getAll(lastNode: Node, buffer: ArrayBuffer[T]): Unit = {
    if (lastNode.value != null)
      buffer.append(lastNode.value.asInstanceOf[T])
    if (lastNode.nodeRoot != null)
      lastNode.nodeRoot.values.foreach(e => {
        getAll(e, buffer)

      })

  }

  def get(key: String): Iterable[T] = {
    val t = findLastNode(key.toCharArray, 0, root)
    println("getting from " + root)
    val isLast = t._2
    if (isLast) {
      val v = t._1.value
      if (v != null)
        return List(v.asInstanceOf[T])
      else
        return null
    } else {
      val buffer = new ArrayBuffer[T]()
      getAll(t._1, buffer)
      return buffer.toList
    }
  }

  private def findLastNode(key: Array[Char], charIdx: Int,
                           root: mutable.Map[Char, Node]): (Node, Boolean) = {
    if (charIdx < key.length - 2 && (key(charIdx + 1) != '*')) {
      return (root(key(charIdx)), false)
    } else if (charIdx < key.length - 1) {
      return findLastNode(key, charIdx + 1, root(key(charIdx)).nodeRoot)
    } else
      return (root(key(charIdx)), true)
  }
}

case class Node(value: Any, private[datastructure] val nodeRoot: mutable.HashMap[Char, Node]) {

}
```

Basically the idea is we look up every character in a subsequent map the complexity would now be the length of the key. Which, really, should be an acceptable limitation since compilation of a reg ex is likely O(N) anyways. Also in cases where you have shorter keys and many entries would yield much better performance then iterating over all the keys. If you swap the mutable.HashMap with some kind of own implementation with clever hashing and take advantage of the fact that a character is really an int, and in case of ASCII strings (which will likely be the key) actually a short. It would also be more difficult if you're looking up some more complex expression then something*, but still likely doable.

edit: a test

```
class MySpec extends PlaySpec {

  val map = new RegExpLookup[String]()

  "RegExpLookup" should {

    "put a bunch of values and get all matching ones" in {
      map.put("abc1", "123")
      map.put("abc2", "456")
      map.put("abc3", "789")
      val result = map.get("abc*")
      println(result)
      val s = result.toSet
      assert(s.contains("123"))
      assert(s.contains("456"))
      assert(s.contains("789"))
    }

    "put a single value and get it by exact key" in {
      map.put("abc", "xyz")
      val result = map.get("abc")
      println(result)
      assert(result.head.equals("xyz"))
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to loop through the Key Set and match the pattern

```
for(String key : map.keySet()) {
   if(! key.startsWith("address")) {
       continue;
   }

   // do whatever you want do as key will be match pattern to reach this code.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need big performance, browsing all the keys on your map (`map.entrySet`) to get the ones matching your pattern should be enough.

If you need good performance, a solution i have used to solve this kind of problem is to use an in-memory database such as H2: you put your data in a memory table, create unique index on the key and you will get good performance for the 2 cases:

- Getting a value associated to the key (`select value from in_mem_table where key = ?'`), classic usage of an hashmap
- Getting values associated to a "key pattern"  (`select value from in_mem_table where key like 'adress%'`)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a function that searches all the map for keys starting with address but that would remove the advantage of the map, since the objective is probably to be fast.
Another way is to create a list or array containing all keys starting with address, but that is only worth if you just want the keys starting with address.

Now do you need to be able to search for anything or just a specific thing? And do you need the map or can it be another thing like an array or list?